# Using Ajax, JavaScript and HTML to post some data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, html

Hello I´m very frustated because I can´t connect to my database to retrieve some files.

I have my normal html code (index.html) which adds a javascript:

```
<script src="js/connection.js"></script>
```

The javascript (connection.js) looks something like this, which detects from a grid of elements the selected element and gets it´s text:

```
var texto="";

function getData($dia){

//Variable $dia is set up correctly, no problem

var dia=$dia;
/* Send the data using post*/
$.ajax({
    url: "php/setup.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {'fecha':dia},
    contentType: "application/json",
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(){
        alert("Exito");
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
});
}

//Get the desired text upon click on the grid item
$(document).ready(function(){    
$(".grid__item").click(function(){
    $texto=$(this).html().substring(($(this).html().indexOf(">"),($(this).html().indexOf(">")+1)),$(this).html().indexOf("</h2>"));
    getData($texto); 
});
});
```

Finally using Ajax I pass the variable 'fecha', the problem is that I think it´s not making a proper connection with my php file since nothing is printing (I have a method which prints to console)

I set the post method like this (**PHP file starts here**):

```
debug_to_console("Print Something");
$fecha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fecha']);
getPageData($fecha);
```

Which calls this method:

```
function getPageData($dia){

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM Comentarios WHERE dia='$dia'");
$result = mysqli_query(connectToDb(),$sql);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$html="";
$boolean=true;
if($num_rows>0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {            
        if($boolean==true){
            $html.='<div class="gray"><div class="comentario">'.$row["comment"].'</div><div class="timestamp">'.$row["dia"].'</div></div>'; 
            $boolean=false;
        }else{
            $html.='<div class="white"><div class="comentario">'.$row["comment"].'</div><div class="timestamp">'.$row["dia"].'</div></div>'; 
            $boolean=true;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode(array('html'=>($html.'<br>'.'<div class="fondo_gen"> div></div></div>'),'texto'=>$dia));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('html'=>'<div class="transparent"><div class="nada">No hay comentarios aun :(</div></div>','texto'=>$dia));
}
}
```

**PHP file ends here**

I know that it's connecting to the database since a made a "dummy.php" file which connects to the same database and table and adds a record, without problem. I´m not really sure which is the problem, I could really appreciate it if you could help me.

PS:

My folders are setup like this:

1. index.html
2. js (folder)
    a. connection.js
3. php (folder)
    a. setup.php

.
Thanks and sorry for my crappy english

Comment: How would you print to the console from a PHP file? Aren't you confused between server side code and client side code? Or maybe you're not talking about the browser console, but another one? From what I see, your JS `getData()` function is not going to print anything apart from an alert.

Comment: And what console does the PHP log to? Are you seeing any of the alerts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What are the post / response show in the browsers console when you perform the AJAX? What errors do you encounter? You have nothing catching any MySQLi errors. In addition, I am concerned about the mix of Mysql functions and MySQLi.

Comment: Hello, the console that is printing in is the one embedded in the browsers (like chrome and internet explorer). It doesn't print any errors actually the success function is triggering saying that everything went as planned. I meant MYSQLi (I keep forgetting is deprecated). If I try to grab the array from the success function it shows undefined (I print it like success: function(data){
        alert(data.html);
    },

Comment: I just got an error from the server side: Notice: undefined index: fecha in (my url) on line 4, which is: $fecha = $_POST["fecha"];

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got it fixed, I replaced the Ajax part with:

```
 $.post("php/setup.php",
{
    fecha: dia
},
function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

and received the variable using

```
if (isset($_POST["fecha"])){
   $fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
   getPageData($fecha);
}else{
   echo "Got nothing";
}
```

Thanks anyway, I appreciate the help